CentOS not updating syslog messages to /var/log/messages
Team,
Below is the shell code, which should send events to syslog and when I ran below code, it does not appear any error but when I check /var/log/messages it does not show up.
#!/bin/bash

# Iterate through all systemctl services and check their status
services=$(systemctl list-unit-files --type=service --no-legend | awk '{print $1}')

for service in $services
do
    status=$(systemctl is-active $service)
    # Send logs to rsyslogd
    echo "$service: $status" | /usr/bin/logger -t "ServiceStatus" -p user.error
done

Due to this azure monitor logs not pushing to server
I have CBL Mariner linux it is working, In cent OS it is not working
Not working OS details:
 os: cent os 7

 rsyslog-8.24.0-57.el7_9.3.x86_64
 rsyslog-gnutls-8.24.0-57.el7_9.3.x86_64


I just tested and it works for me. Here's my details:
cat /etc/centos-release
CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611 (Core)
yum list installed | grep rsyslog
rsyslog.x86_64           7.4.7-16.el7
Not an answer, just adding info that may help you find the answer :)

i have 8.2 version in diffrent Linux platform that is also working

Running your script as root? Can you manually send a simple test message through logger (echo 'message #1' | logger -t test -p user.err)? Can you add a echo "$service: $status" line inside your loop, to confirm that the loop is correctly executed?
